# Translating C++ program to JavaScript/asm.js does not produce the same sequence of numbers

Tags: javascript, c++, v8, low-level, asm.js

I took the mother of all random number generators from Agner Fog's library and attempted to make a JavaScript version of this. I expect the bit pattern to be identical but this doesn't seem to be the case and I wonder why or if I made a mistake?

The C++ code I use can be found [here](https://replit.com/@JohnLeidegren/GentleTubbyErrors#main.cpp). It's from Agner Fog's [website](https://www.agner.org/random/).

Here's my TypeScript version of this code

```
const u = (function () {
  const b = new ArrayBuffer(8)
  return {
    u32: new Uint32Array(b),
    u64: new BigUint64Array(b),
  }
})()

export class Random {
  state = new Uint32Array(5)

  constructor(seed?: number) {
    this.seed(seed ?? +new Date())
  }

  b() {
    const { state: x } = this

    u.u64[0] =
      2111111111n * BigInt(x[3]) +
      1492n * BigInt(x[2]) +
      1776n * BigInt(x[1]) +
      5115n * BigInt(x[0]) +
      BigInt(x[4])

    console.debug(u.u64[0])

    x[3] = x[2]
    x[2] = x[1]
    x[1] = x[0]
    x[4] = u.u32[1]
    x[0] = u.u32[0]

    return x[0]
  }

  next() {
    return (1 / 4_294_967_296) * this.b()
  }

  seed(seed: number) {
    const { state: x } = this

    let s = seed >>> 0
    // make random numbers and put them into the buffer
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      s = s * 29943829 - 1
      x[i] = s
    }

    console.debug(x)

    // randomize some more
    for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
      this.b()
    }
  }
}
```

I managed to get it down to the the state initialization but I cannot understand why the output from the C++ program is `4294967295`, `4265023466`, `1627457073`, `3925469700`, `2226377299` but the TypeScript program is giving me `4294967295`, `4265023466`, `1627457073`, `3925868544`, `0`. Only the first 3 numbers get computed exactly the same. Any help trying to understand this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I figured it out. I have to use `Math.imul` to get correct results. Can't do C-like integer multiplication without it.

So, this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  s = s * 29943829 - 1
  x[i] = s
}
```

...changes into:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  s = Math.imul(s, 29943829) - 1
  x[i] = s
}
```

I tried stuff like `(s * 29943829) >>> 0` but this is not enough to force C style integer multiplication.

Comment: As an alternative you could use BigInt multiplication. That said, `Math.imul` is likely faster, because it's been around longer so engines have had more time to implement full optimization support for it. The core issue is that `*` on Number inputs performs a 64-bit floating-point multiplication, which produces a result with 53 bits of precision; taking the lower half of that with `>>> 0` includes some of the "lost" bits.

Comment: @jmrk that explains why it worked for at least 3 rounds.

Comment: @jmrk since you work on V8 stuff, whenever you do multiplication, is it always floating point math? How does V8 know to do integer math and not floating point?

Comment: It's not up to V8. JavaScript `Number` multiplication is required to always behave as if it was a 64-bit floating-point multiplication. There may be cases where an engine can prove that using an integer instruction doesn't change the result; off the top of my head I'm not sure whether this is ever done for multiplication. A JS engine will never use integer math for Numbers when doing so would change the result. With `Math.imul`, on the other hand, the engine knows that it _must_ use integer multiplication. Of course, `BigInt` multiplication also uses integer instructions.

Comment: @jmrk wow, that is surprising to me... I thought it would favor integer operations, I mean, doesn't all numbers within range default to SMI?

BigInt though... that's a heap allocated object. The only magic I know of is the `BigInt.asInt(64, ...` trick which does work with addition and subtraction. It is the only special case that I know that is actually fast.